# Hotkey to close toast notification

Tags: windows, process, autohotkey, notifications

**Goal**: close [Clock](https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/windows-clock/9WZDNCRFJ3PR?hl=en-us&gl=GE) app's toast notification with a hotkey combination.

**Attempt**: AHK's `Process, Close, ahk_pid`, but `ahk_pid` changes each time. I've also been unable to find the popup window's process in Task Manager (not to imply it doesn't exist). Closing the app itself in Task Manager doesn't remove the alarm.

Can this be done? I simply need the alarm to stop bleeping, *without* muting volume, and without having to use the mouse in any way. Windows 11.

Comment: Use Start, Systems, Notifications, Set Priority Notifications and turn OFF the clock.

Comment: Doesn't work, and I used do not disturb mode.

Comment: I do not know why.  No Clock notifications and alarms here.

Comment: The goal's to _remove_ a notification, not _prevent_ it. And it is critical that future notifications aren't averted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From
[Dismiss Windows 10 Notification From Keyboard](https://winaero.com/dismiss-windows-10-notification-from-keyboard/) :

> 1. Press Win+Shift+V
> 2. This will move the focus to the notification (will activate it and bring to front)
> 3. Now, press the Delete key
> 4. The notification will instantly disappear.

If this is still too much work, you may use a macro processor such as
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/),
to bundle it all into one shortcut.

Comment: Sometimes I think, _you_ made Windows!